# How to find version of CKEDITOR Inline

Tags: ckeditor

I have CKEDITOR inline embedded in my portal but I am unable to find the version of CKEDITOR.

`CKEDITOR.version` returns `%VERSION%`

The changes.md file doesn't exist either.

Answer (score 0):

If `CKEDITOR.version` is set to `%VERSION%` it means that you're using a development version of CKEditor, not a release (or that it was built incorrectly). Lack of changelog means that someone removed it... Not a very fortunate move as well. So if you don't know its source and its not a clone of CKEditor repository it will be very hard to guess what version it is. You can try to check `CKEDITOR.revision` and compare it with http://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev. But if that fails too, then the only solution will be to compare code manually.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.revision` returns `%REVISION%`